# Перевернуть 2 колонки из таблицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Помогите пожалуйста. Есть таблица, нужно перевернуть 2 колонки и сделать из них строки.
При этом "сочетание" значений из первых колонок должно повторяться, а остальные составить уникальные сочетания.
В колонке Col_Name - названия будущих колонок (вариаций много), а в Value - значения для этих колонок

Т.е. из такой таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно получить такую:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовала воспользоваться pandas - pivot, но агрегация не получается.
Как по другому ее перевернуть не знаю :(

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': ['10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236'], 
        'ITEM_NO': ['00001', '00001', '00001', '00001', '00001', '00001', '00001'], 
        'COL_NAME': ['CODE_ETSNG', 'CODE_ETSNG', 'ROAD_FROM', 'ROAD_FROM', 'ROAD_FROM', 'ROAD_FROM', 'SUB_RPS'], 
        'VALUE': ['693227', '521*', '17', '63', '58', '24', '003']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

res = (df
       .assign(idx=df.groupby(["ID", 'ITEM_NO']).cumcount())
       .pivot_table(index=["ID", 'ITEM_NO'], columns="COL_NAME", 
                    values="VALUE", aggfunc="unique"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Кривенько, но вроде работает. Точно есть куда улучшать, но пока так.
Данных добавил для тестирования.
Поворот - `pivot`-ом, сочетания - `MultiIndex.from_product()`-ом

```
data = {'ID': ['10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236', '10001017236'],
        'ITEM_NO': ['00001', '00001', '00001', '00001', '00001', '00001', '00001'],
        'COL_NAME': ['CODE_ETSNG', 'CODE_ETSNG', 'ROAD_FROM', 'ROAD_FROM', 'ROAD_FROM', 'ROAD_FROM', 'SUB_RPS'],
        'VALUE': ['693227', '521*', '17', '63', '58', '24', '003']}
data1 = {'ID': ['10001056908'], 'ITEM_NO': ['00001'], 'COL_NAME': ['SUB_RPS'], 'VALUE': ['003']}

def fun(x):
    l = x[['ID', 'ITEM_NO']].head(1).values[0]  # извлекаем значения 'ID', 'ITEM_NO' для последующего заполнения
    x = x.pivot(columns='COL_NAME')['VALUE']  # поворачиваем фрейм
    y = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(x.apply(lambda c: c.dropna().tolist()).values).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)  # создаем уникальные сочетания
    y.columns = x.columns  # возвращаем имена колонок на место
    y.insert(0, 'ITEM_NO', l[1])  # создаем столбец ITEM_NO и заполняем ранее сохраненным значением
    y.insert(0, 'ID', l[0])  # создаем столбец ID и заполняем ранее сохраненным значением
    return y


df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data),pd.DataFrame(data1)])
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'ITEM_NO'], as_index=False).apply(fun).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns.name = None
print(df)
```

```
            ID ITEM_NO CODE_ETSNG ROAD_FROM SUB_RPS
0  10001017236   00001     693227        17     003
1  10001017236   00001     693227        63     003
2  10001017236   00001     693227        58     003
3  10001017236   00001     693227        24     003
4  10001017236   00001       521*        17     003
5  10001017236   00001       521*        63     003
6  10001017236   00001       521*        58     003
7  10001017236   00001       521*        24     003
8  10001056908   00001        NaN       NaN     003
```

Дополнение. Ошибка, возникающая при условии *"если появляется ID & ITEM_NO, у которого не все имена колонок, а например только одна"*, устранена добавлением `.values` в строке `y = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(x.apply(lambda c: c.dropna().tolist()).values).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам ОГРОМНОЕ!! Работает!

Comment: нет все таки не совсем корректно работает :( В примере было так, что у каждого нового ID & ITEM_NO одинаковый набор "будущих колонок". Однако, если появляется ID & ITEM_NO, у которого не все имена колонок, а например только одна (data2 = {'ID': ['10001056908'], 'ITEM_NO': ['00001'], 'COL_NAME': ['SUB_RPS'], 'VALUE': ['003']} .. выдает ошибку "KeyError: "None of [Index(['ID', 'ITEM_NO'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"".

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: @Masik код обновил

Comment: теперь ему другая строка не нравится
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\My_Work\TEO_Compleate\test.py", line 30, in <module>
    df = df.groupby(['ID', 'ITEM_NO'], as_index=False).apply(fun).reset_index(drop=True)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\My_Work\TEO_Compleate\test.py", line 19, in fun
    y.columns = x.columns  # возвращаем имена колонок на место
    ^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 4 elements